# How to debug "exited with code 5" on Simulator

Tags: iphone, debugging

Is there a good way to debug "exited with code 5" runtime error on the iPhone Simulator?

I  know this must be a real NOOB question, but any tips would be appreciated.  Thanks.

I am trying to follow along with the "B[uild your First iPhone App](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html)" tutorial on DevCenter and it seems that I started getting the error when I tried to customize the MyViewController UILabel a little too much.

**Edit:**

Nevermind - I was using the "Build and Debug" option in XCode, which launches the Simulator and causes it to exit with code 5 right away, but when I launch my app a second time, by clicking on the icon, it works fine.

Also - I tried cleaning my targets - and now it doesn't ever give me the code 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the "Build and Debug" option in XCode, which launches the app in the Simulator and causes it to exit with code 5 right away the first time. When I launched my app a second time, by clicking on the icon in the Simulator, it worked fine.

Also - I tried cleaning my targets - and now it doesn't ever give me the code 5.